# Dynamic File Name in a ICS generator

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I'm trying to write a ical generator with some tweaks, here and there. Is it possible to make the name if the .ics file dynamic depending on what the user typed in the Person text field - The file name should be the same as the content in the "Person Textfield" I tried a query selector but that didn't seem to work and in other tries he didn't return as a .ics file

Here is a short code snippet

```
<section>
  <label for="person">Person</label>
  <input id="person" type="text" placeholder="Enter person"/>    
</section>
.
.
.
<section>
  <button id="create">Create file</button><a class="download e" id="downloadLink" download="(#person).ics"> Download</a>
</section>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks